# Gitlab API post base64 image

Tags: javascript, gitlab, fetch

I would like POST new issue using Gitlab API with `gfm` params for using Markdown.

I can only get image with base64 format. So, i've try to use markdown for show base64 image :

`![MyImage](${base64})`

But It does not seem to work because image don't show and the base64 code is the Gitlab placeholder :

`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==`

Anyone have already work with attachment Gitlab API ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answers your question about posting an base64 image, but might fit your needs. GitLab allows to upload files to use in issue, merge request description, or comments.

1. Create a **Projekt Token** having the role `guest` and the permission to access the `api`.
2. **Upload** the image to `/uploads` (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#upload-a-file). Provide the token, the file and your project id (73 in my case).

   ```bash
   curl --request POST \
        --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" \
        --form "file=@test.png" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/73/uploads"
   ```

   GitLab's API will answer your request by supplying the *markdown* ready to use.

   ```json
   {
     "alt":"test",
     "url":"/uploads/ce8ed96ebc071d50ea887fb207909338/test.png",
     "full_path":"/example-group/example-project/uploads/ce8ed96ebc071d50ea887fb207909338/test.png",
     "markdown":"![test](/uploads/ce8ed96ebc071d50ea887fb207909338/test.png)"
   }
   ```
3. Use your uploaded image when
   **creating an issue** (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue)

   ```bash
   curl --request POST \
        --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data '{"title": "Test Issue 01","description":"![test](/uploads/ce8ed96ebc071d50ea887fb207909338/test.png)"}' \
        https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/73/issues
   ```

   If more convenient, the data can be supplied from a file using `--data @data.json`.